# fig.keep = 'all' only keeps 2

Tags: r, plot, graph, r-markdown, knitr

I want to output multiple identical plots in R Markdown to pdf, and I see I should use "fig.keep = 'all'" to do so. But it only keeps the first two plots, the rest are discarded.

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

```
for(i in 1:10){
  plot(1,3)
}
```

break between chunks

```
for(i in list(1,2,3,'a',1,2,3)){
  tryCatch({
    w = sqrt(i)
    plot(1,3)
  },
  error = function(e){
    plot.new()
    title('error')
  })
}
```

The result is a pdf with two plots on the first two pages, then the "break between code chunks for visibility" line, then another two plots on another two pages, then the "error" plot, then another two plots on another two pages.  But what I was expecting was 10 plots, then the text line, then 3 plots, 1 error plot, and then another 3 plots.

Where can I find the documentation for this behavior? I know the knitr engine checks for identical plots and also keeps the "high" level plotting command results, but I thought fig.keep = 'all' should override them.